# Could we see through objects if our eye could detect other wavelengths of light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, wavelength, x-rays, optical-materials

We see objects around us because light reflects off the surface and enters our eye. So if our eyes could see a wider range of the spectrum (maybe lower wavelength as they would scatter less) then would we be able to see through objects?

Answer (score 4):

We can already see through objects like glass. Colored glass transmits certain wavelengths and not others. If our eyes could see more wavelengths than presently this would be no different . For example pure silicon transmits far infrared. If we could see far infrared it would look like a sort of glass with what would be infrared color. Metals can be transparent in ultraviolet.

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision

Answer (score 0):

Yes we could see through objects more if that were the case. Some wavelengths of electromagnetic waves are more penetrative than others in different materials. For example radio frequencies(RF) can travel through concrete walls, so if you could see them, you could see the antennas of the wifi router or where phone towers are located through walls